# How to use Terraform Module for cross-account work

Tags: terraform, aws-codepipeline

I create a codepipeline at dev_account, it triggers both codedeploy at dev_account, test_account and prod_account, the codedeploy of three accounts looks the same except they are in different accounts.

Below is the organization of my terraform files. I use terraform module to reuse code but I still think my code has a lot of duplicate code, how to optimize them?

```
common_infr/
    codepipeline.tf # dev_account has codepipeline, codedeploy 
    codedeploy.tf   
    test_account/
        codedeploy.tf # test_account has a codedeploy
    prod_account/
        codedeploy.tf # prod_account has a codedeploy
pipeline1/
    main.tf #run terraform apply here using dev account
    test_account/
        main.tf #run terraform apply here using test account
    prod_account/
        main.tf #run terraform apply here using prod account
```

This is pipeline1/main.tf:

```
module "pipeline1" {
  source       = "../common_infra"
  variable1    = "..."
  ...
}
```

This is pipeline1/test_account/main.tf:

```
module "pipeline1" {
  source       = "../../common_infra/test_account"
  variable1    = "..."
  ...
}
```

this is pipeline1/prod_account/main.tf:

```
module "pipeline1" {
  source       = "../../common_infra/prod_account"
  variable1    = "..."
  ...
}
```

the codedeploy.tf of three accounts look the same. how to optimize this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of creating 3 modules for each account's `codedeploy.tf`, create a single `codedeploy` module. In each account's main.tf, source the `codedeploy` module and [pass in the account's provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/usage.html#passing-providers-explicitly). Here's what `test_account` might look like.

```
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "test_account"
  profile = "your_profile_name_for_test_account"
}

module "pipeline1" {
  providers = {
    aws = "aws.test_account"
  }
  source       = "../../common_infra/codedeploy"
  variable1    = "..."
  ...
}
```

---

Editing to elaborate on the directory layout. Ultimately, you're removing `codepipeline` from the `common_infr` and putting it into its own module.

```
modules/
  codepipeline/
    codepipeline.tf
  common_infr/
    codedeploy.tf

accounts/
  test_account/
    main.tf
  prod_account/
    main.tf
```

test_account/main.tf:

```
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "test_account"
  profile = "your_profile_name_for_test_account"
}

module "pipeline1" {
  providers = {
    aws = "aws.test_account"
  }
  source       = "../modules/codepipeline"
  variable1    = "..."
  ...
}

module "common_infr" {
  providers = {
    aws = "aws.test_account"
  }
  source       = "../modules/common_infr"
  variable1    = "..."
  ...
}
```

prod_account/main.tf:

```
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "prod_account"
  profile = "your_profile_name_for_prod_account"
}

module "common_infr" {
  providers = {
    aws = "aws.prod_account"
  }
  source       = "../modules/common_infr"
  variable1    = "..."
  ...
}
```

Comment: justMiles: Thanks for answering me! what is your structure of common_infra? where is your codepipeline in the structure? do you mean  the structure becomes common_infra/codepipeline.tf and  common_infra/codedeploy/codedeploy.tf? Note When I terraform apply in dev_account, I want to create both codepipeline and codedeploy. but when I terraform apply in test_account and prod_account, only codedeploy should be created there,

Comment: justMiles: besides, using your solution, do I need to run twice in dev_account? once to source: common_infra/codepipeline which is to get codepipeline, once to source: common_infra/codedeploy in order to get codedeploy at dev_account? Thanks.

Comment: @user389955, you would only run it once. I updated my comment with what the directory layout could look like.

Comment: justMiles: Oh, I understand what you mean now. good to know I can do that way. I will verify whether it works. I appreciate your help!